# "request a copy of document" log

Tags: dspace

I'd like to track down the sequence of events in a 'request a copy of a document' transaction from the logs.  I've been grepping (-i) for 'request a copy' and various combinations in my dspace and tomcat logs, but I can't readily see anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request-a-copy code doesn't log things. I patched [ItemRequestResponseAction](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/artifactbrowser/ItemRequestResponseAction.java) (link to 5.x version of code) to add logging in a few spots -- basically every time after `email.send()` is invoked.

Unfortunately, I think your best bet might be the Apache logs, if you have access to those. I don't remember too much about the URL patterns to look for, but the ViewArtifacts sitemap suggests "restricted-resource" might be good (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/ViewArtifacts/sitemap.xmap#L132), as might "itemRequestResponse" (https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-xmlui/src/main/resources/aspects/ViewArtifacts/sitemap.xmap#L292) (check for `map:match` blocks that invoke `ItemRequest*` classes).